# Laravel return value of a specific column in a relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am extremely new to Laravel. You could help me with a small problem:
I can not return in a collection, only the value of a specific column in a relation defined in the model. I will explain:

I have 2 tables:

1 - Tomos

2 - Documents

**Migrations:**

1- Tomos

```php
    private $table = 'tomos';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable(false);
            $table->text('description')->nullable(true);
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

2- Documents

```php
private $table = 'documents';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('date')->nullable(false);
            $table->integer('provider_id');
            $table->integer('tomo_id');
            $table->string('folio')->nullable(false);
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('provider_id')
                ->references('id')->on('providers');

            $table->foreign('tomo_id')
                ->references('id')->on('tomos');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

**Relations**

1- Tomo

```php
public function document()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
}
```

2- Document

```php
public function tomo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tomo::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```php
class Documents extends Controller
{
    public function read(Request $request)
    {
        $provider = $request->only('id');

        $documents = Document::select(['id', 'date', 'tomo_id', 'description'])
            ->with([
                'tomo' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id', 'name');
                }
            ])->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(25);

        return $documents;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following response in JSON:

```php
current_page    1
    data    […]
        0   {…}
            id  2
            date    2018-12-01
            tomo_id 1
            description 1
            tomo    {…}
                id  1
                name    Tomo 1
```

But ... I do not want the key ('tomo') to return an object, I want it to return the value of the column ('name') as a string. Example:

```php
current_page    1
    data    […]
        0   {…}
            id  2
            date    2018-12-01
            tomo_id 1
            description 1
            tomo Tomo 1
```

Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: The fastest way to do that is to use join instead of the relation, i will try to think of something else to solve this.

Comment: Oh you can use custom attributes, i will write an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add `protected $appends = array('tomo_name');` as attribute, because this is one that doesn't exist on the model table.

```
 public function getTomoNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->tomo()->name;  
}
```

After this, you can access the tomo name like this `->tomo_name`

I'm not 100% sure that this code will work with just copy paste, but you might get the idea and work on it a little bit more.

Oh and be aware that loading the attribute, will query the database for that "tomo" every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to: **Peter** and **Munteanu Petrisor**

In special to : **Munteanu Petrisor**

I have been able to solve my problem with the solution that you propose to me, previously I had achieved it using **'join'**:

```
class Documents extends Controller
{
    public function read(Request $request)
    {
        $provider = $request->only('id');

        $documents = Document::join('tomos', 'documents.tomo_id', '=', 'tomos.id')
            ->join('users', 'documents.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where(['provider_id' => $provider])
            ->paginate(25, array(
                'documents.id',
                'documents.date',
                'documents.folio',
                'documents.description',
                'tomos.name as tomo',
            ));

        return $documents;
    }
}
```

And now with your help, using **attributes** works wonders:

**Document Model**

```
protected $appends = [
    'tomo_name',
    'user_fullname'
];

public function getTomoNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->tomo()->first()->name;
}

public function getUserFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->user()->first()->first_name . ' ' . $this->user()->first()->last_name;
}
```

**Document Controller**

```
class Documents extends Controller
{
    public function read(Request $request)
    {
        $provider = $request->only('id');

        $documents = Document::select(['id', 'date', 'tomo_id', 'user_id', 'folio', 'description'])
            ->where(['provider_id' => $provider])
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(25);

        return $documents;
    }
}
```

And now it returns the data the way I expected

```
data    […]
    0   {…}
        id  2
        date    2018-12-01
        tomo_id 1
        user_id 1
        folio   1
        description 1
        tomo_name   1
        user_fullname   First Last
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Documents extends Controller
{
    public function read(Request $request)
    {
        $provider = $request->only('id');

        $documents = Document::select(['id', 'date', 'tomo_id', 'description'])
            ->with('tomo:id,name') // get relationship with id and name
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(25);

        return $documents;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your controller, try:

```
$documents->getCollection()->transform(function ($item) {
    $item->tomo = $item->tomo->name;
    return $item;
});
return $documents;
```

Comment: I think this is bad because he has to get all the documents and loop on them to change the attribute.

Comment: Maybe, but he's only getting 25 records. Collections are there for a reason and it's a valid use case. The attribute solution you proposed is very good too but as you say it has its downsides too.

Comment: Your solution has exactly the same downside, oh, and on both cases you can load the relations before, that way you might reduce the number of queries. Another thing, that paginate(25) could be any number, usually  it is either 10,15,25, 50 and 100 . 100 is pretty large, because the size of the object itself counts and what you want to do with them

Comment: Your solution is valid, it works, but i think it is only good for collections that are coming on small numbers, something like "settings" or stuff that is static and not likely to become large